# .net Framework version folders?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

Looking at current folder structure :

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework -
 1. v1.0.3705
 2. v1.1.4322
 3. v2.0.50727
 4. v3.0
 5. v3.5
 6. v4.0.30319
```

And on the 64 ver :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64-
 1. v2.0.50727
 2. v3.0
 3. v3.5
 4. v4.0.30319
```

And here is my question :

I've installed today `4.5.1` :

[image]

But I **don't** see any folder for that version ( nor for `4.5`).

If `3`,`3.5` are built on `2` and they do got special folder ( as you can see) - then why `4.5`/`4.5.1` didn't get their own folder ? what is so special about the way this version was embedded ?

Comment: It is v3.0 and v3.5 that are the odd ducks, you can tell from their missing build number.  There have only ever been four CLR versions.  No idea why they got special treatment back then.

Comment: @HansPassant 4 versions ? [not 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx) ? (1,2,4)

Comment: Numbers 1, 2, 3 and 6 in your list.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought that `1.1.4322` was an update to ver 1. I guess I wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to the big commotion of a year or two ago. 4.5 is a in place upgrade of 4.0, it overwrites files in the 4.0 folder to do the install.

**UPDATE**: I found [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx) that states you can still access the overwritten reference assemblies in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework` but those are not the assemblies that are used at runtime on your machine. If you have 4.5 installed a 4.0 targeted assembly will use the 4.5 dll's.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking, no one knows anything until they hear about it for the first time. Sorry for my snark level, I guess my morning coffee did not kick in yet.